# How do I turn Ubuntu 12.04 server into an open SOCKS5 proxy?

Tags: proxy, socks5

I'd like to set up a socks5 proxy based on my ubuntu 12.04 server.

I've [read](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/linux-socks5-proxy/) that this is supposed to be easy and doable with one command:

```
ssh -f -N -D 0.0.0.0:1080 localhost
```

Not so much in my case (error message):

```
Permission denied (publickey).
```

After this, I've tried installing [ss5](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ss5/).

First from source:

```
wget http://heanet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/ss5/ss5/3.8.9-7/ss5-3.8.9-7.tar.gz
tar -zxvf *.tar.gz
cd *
./configure
```

Which ended in

```
configure: error: *** Some of the headers weren't found ***
```

After which I attempted to i[nstall it from rpm](http://shellboy.com/ss5-socks-proxy-server-with-user-authentication.html), without much luck:

```
error: Failed build dependencies:
        openldap-devel is needed by ss5-3.8.9-6.i386
        pam-devel is needed by ss5-3.8.9-6.i386
        openssl-devel is needed by ss5-3.8.9-6.i386
        libgssapi-devel is needed by ss5-3.8.9-6.i386

....

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package openldap-devel
```

There are other packages for socks5, but I've met similar problems with them too.

Can anyone point me to a good info on how to turn ubuntu 12.04 server into a socks5 proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the first error easily:

Go into the dash, and search *Passwords and Keys*. Go into your keys and go to File>New and chose the SSH key. Don't give it a password. Then, set it to use RSA, any key size, and then when prompted to set it up to be used for logon, allow it to do so, and choose the following settings:

Hostname: `localhost`
Username: Your username

and give your password if prompted. Reboot and try again with the first command.

Comment: I'm doing this on server via ssh. Could you provide the commands for what you just said?

Comment: Just give the hostname and user on the server instead of `localhost`. Run the graphical program on your local machine, then try it again.

Comment: Also, is the first error when you run the command,or try to connect?